# Changing column names of many dataframes in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have three dataframes EC_Data, ED_Data, and ST_data
all of them have the same column names and more specifically, after 4th column
has Year named colums from 2006 to 2015

So I create a new list that has all three dataframes:

```
Alldata = list(EC_Data, ED_Data, ST_Data)
```

So I tried to rename all the columns in a for loop like below...

```
for(x in seq_along(Alldata))
{
  for(j in seq_along(Alldata[[x]]))
  {
    if(j>4)
    {
      names(colnames(Alldata[[x]][j])) <- paste("X", substr(colnames(Alldata[[x]][j]), start = 1, stop = 5),sep="")
      print(colnames(Alldata[[x]][j]))
    }
  }
}
```

But nothing happens...

I cannot understand why, because when I try to call the names of every list, for example  with

```
view(colnames(Alldata[[2]]))
```

the names seems to be exactly what I want to see

Can someone help me to understand the reason that this loop doesn't work and what can I use instead of this?

Thank you

Comment: you don't need `names(colnames(...))` does just `colnames(...)` work?

Comment: The first thing I did was that... Just colnames, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to rename all the columns use `lapply` to loop over the `list`, `paste` with the `substr` of the existing column names and assign them with `setNames`

```
Alldata <- lapply(Alldata, function(x) 
      setNames(x, paste0("X", substr(colnames(x), 1, 5))))
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(Alldata)) {
      Alldata[[i]] <- setNames(Alldata[[i]], 
           paste0("X", substr(colnames(Alldata[[i]]), 1, 5))
  }
```

Comment: lapply worked as you said.

Thank you very much for your response.